Embedding a full React application in an Expo WebView for offline use
The React app consists of multiple .js files and an index.html, along with additional resources like GLTF and PNG files. The issue arises due to the CORS policy preventing file/folder separation in an offline context. I attempted to use vite-plugin-singlefile to bundle my React project into a single index.html file, but encountered a problem with including assets like PNG and GLTF files in the .html file. The WebView is blocked by the CORS policy when trying to access these assets. The only workaround I've found is to serve the React app online (e.g., via http://localhost), but I need the Expo WebView to function offline without serving the app remotely. I tried to bypass the CORS policy without success. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
Those are the kinds of error that are raised:

Error: Unauthorized request from http://127.0.0.1:8081. This may happen because of a conflicting browser extension to intercept HTTP requests. Please try again without browser extensions or using incognito mode.


Access to script at 'file:///C:/assets/index-CYC07tOJ.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

